# Subtraction between two binomial variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-theorem

Assuming X and Y are two independent binomial random variables:

$X$~$B(n_x,\alpha)$,  $Y$~$B(n_y,\alpha)$

What can be said about the distribution of $Z$ where $Z=Y-X$.

Specifically does $Z$ PDF is a unimodal function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the function $f(z) = \mathop{\text{Prob}}(Z=z)$
is a unimodal function of the integer $z$.
[Hm, is it kosher to call $f$ a "probability *density* function"
in this discrete setting?]  More generally, this is true for any
variable of the form $Z = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where
the $X_i$ are independent random variables each taking the value
$1$ with probability $p_i$ and $0$ with probability $q_i = 1 - p_i$.
To see that our $Z=X-Y$, with $X \sim B(n_x,\alpha)$ and $Y \sim B(n_y,\alpha)$,
is indeed a special case,
set $n=n_x+n_y$, $\;p_i = \alpha$ for $i \leq n_x$, and $q_i = \alpha$ for
$i > n_x$, and then shift by $n_y$.

Once the result is stated in this more general form, it can be proved
by induction on $n$.  The base case $n=0$ is clear, because then
$f(0)=1$ and $f(z)=0$ for all $z \neq 0$.  Assume we have proven
the result for $n-1$, so $Z_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i$ has PDF
$f_1(z) = \mathop{\text{Prob}}(Z_1=z)$ unimodal with maximum $z_1$.
Then $f(z) = p_n\,f_1(z) + q_n\,f_1(z-1)$, so 
$f(z)\leq f(z')$ for $z \leq z' \leq z_1$
and $f(z)\geq f(z')$ for $z_1 < z \leq z'$.
Therefore $f$ is unimodal with maximum $z_1$ or $z_1+1$.
This completes the induction step and the proof.

The same technique proves more generally that the function $\lambda^z f(z)$
is unimodal for all $\lambda > 0$; equivalently, $f$ is not just
unimodal but *log-concave*: $f(z)^2 \geq f(z-1) \, f(z+1)$ for all $z$
(and in our case equality holds only when $f(z)=0$).

Answer (score 1):

The modality component is already answered. This answer derives a 'closed-form' solution for the pmf. If I may change the notation slightly, and make it more general (allowing each Binomial to have different parameters):

**The Problem**

> Let $X_1$ ~ $Binomial(n,p)$ and $X_2$ ~ $Binomial(m,q)$ be independent.
>
> Find the pmf of $Z = X_1-X_2$

Given: Due to independence, the joint pmf of $(X_1, X_2)$, say $f(x_1,x_2)$, is:

[image]

**Solution**

Let $Z=X_1-X_2$ and $Y=X_2$. Then, the joint pmf of $(Z,Y)$, say $g(z,y)$, is:

[image]

where I am using the `Transform` function from the `mathStatica` package to automate the derivation of the joint pmf using the *Method of Transformations* (I am one of the authors of the package). Deriving the domain of support of $Y$ and $Z$ is a bit more tricky. To make things clearer, here is a rough diagram that illustrates the (smoothed continuous version of) the domain of support:

[image]

This suggests two cases:

- Case 1:  When $z \ge 0$:  $0 \le y \le n-z$
- Case 2:  When $z < 0$:  $-z \le y \le m$

The pmf of $Z=X_1-X_2$ is then obtained by summing out $Y$ in each part of the domain:

[image]

---

**In summary:** The pmf of $Z=X_1-X_2$, say $h(z)$, is:

$$ h(z) = \begin{cases}\text{pmfCase1} & z = 0,1, \dots, n\\ \text{pmfCase2} & z = -1, -2, \dots, -m  \end{cases}$$

---

All done.

Here is a quick plot of the derived pmf of $Z=X_1-X_2$ (the blue round dots), when $n = 3, m = 9, p = .8, q =.4$. The red triangles are a quick Monte Carlo check super-imposed on top, just to make sure everything is correct ...

[image]